# Meshes don't render in cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, animation, materials

I started to use Blender to make Intros and stuff.

Right now I'm working on a very complex intro with animations and other stuff. Everything works pretty well except the rendering. When I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> I just have my World Color but no Meshes.

By the way, I am using Cycles to render.

When I go to the "Realtime" Render view I can see the meshes and Shadows but these Meshes have the same color like the world color even when I apply some materials.

Comment: Very hard to help you without screenshots and or a blend file.

Answer (score 2):

You camera must be placed and directed to render appropriately.  (User Views) and Camera View are not the same.  Press 0 zero in 3D View Mode to see camera view.  I would put this under a comment if I could.  I am new at this site.